# How to transfer int from one .java class to another? Having issues with common ways

Tags: android

My goal in this question is push the rssilevel from one .java file to the other.

I tried to push from class 1 to class 2, as well as pulling data dfrom class 1 to class 2 and i have always had my app crash.

I tried 
ProximityManager temp = new ProximityManager();
int temp = temp.rssilevel;

The above code is in a class in the same package, but different .java file and class. They are linked.

and it would not work, any other ideas please!

EDIT: Also how would i call the function playSound() in another class?

i would normaly do something like Public ProximityManager mProximityManager;
then call mProximityManager.playSound(); but i get an app crash when i do this.

```
public class ProximityManager implements BleManager<ProximityManagerCallbacks> {
private final String TAG = "ProximityManager";

private ProximityManagerCallbacks mCallbacks;
private BluetoothGattServer mBluetoothGattServer;
private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
private BluetoothDevice mDeviceToConnect;
private Context mContext;
private Handler mHandler;
private LogSession mLogSession;
private Ringtone mRingtoneNotification;
private Ringtone mRingtoneAlarm;
public int rssilevel;


public final static UUID IMMEIDIATE_ALERT_SERVICE_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001802-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
public final static UUID LINKLOSS_SERVICE_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

private static final UUID ALERT_LEVEL_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002A06-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

private final static UUID BATTERY_SERVICE_UUID = UUID.fromString("0000180F-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
private final static UUID BATTERY_LEVEL_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID = UUID.fromString("00002A19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
private final static UUID TX_POWER_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001804-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

private final static String ERROR_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE = "Error on connection state change";
private final static String ERROR_DISCOVERY_SERVICE = "Error on discovering services";
private final static String ERROR_AUTH_ERROR_WHILE_BONDED = "Phone has lost bonding information";
private final static String ERROR_WRITE_CHARACTERISTIC = "Error on writing characteristic";
private final static String ERROR_READ_CHARACTERISTIC = "Error on reading characteristic";

private final static int HIGH_ALERT = 2;
private final static int MID_ALERT = 1;
private final static int NO_ALERT = 0;

private BluetoothGattCharacteristic mAlertLevelCharacteristic, mLinklossCharacteristic, mBatteryCharacteristic;

private boolean userDisconnectedFlag = false;

public void getrssi( int rssilevel) {
    this.rssilevel = rssilevel;
}

public ProximityManager(Context context) {
    initializeAlarm(context);

    mHandler = new Handler();

    // Register bonding broadcast receiver
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
    context.registerReceiver(mBondingBroadcastReceiver, filter);
}

private void openGattServer(Context context, BluetoothManager manager) {
    mBluetoothGattServer = manager.openGattServer(context, mGattServerCallbacks);

}

private void closeGattServer() {
    if (mBluetoothGattServer != null) {
        // mBluetoothGattServer.cancelConnection(mBluetoothGatt.getDevice()); // FIXME this method does not cancel the connection
        mBluetoothGattServer.close(); // FIXME This method does not cause BluetoothGattServerCallback#onConnectionStateChange(newState=DISCONNECTED) to be called on Nexus phones.
        mBluetoothGattServer = null;
    }
}

private void addImmediateAlertService() {
    /*
     * This method must be called in UI thread. It works fine on Nexus devices but if called from other thread (f.e. from onServiceAdded in gatt server callback) it hangs the app. 
     */
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic alertLevel = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(ALERT_LEVEL_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);
    alertLevel.setValue(HIGH_ALERT, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);
    BluetoothGattService immediateAlertService = new BluetoothGattService(IMMEIDIATE_ALERT_SERVICE_UUID, BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);
    immediateAlertService.addCharacteristic(alertLevel);
    mBluetoothGattServer.addService(immediateAlertService);
}

private void addLinklossService() {
    /*
     * This method must be called in UI thread. It works fine on Nexus devices but if called from other thread (f.e. from onServiceAdded in gatt server callback) it hangs the app. 
     */
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic linklossAlertLevel = new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(ALERT_LEVEL_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE
            | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_READ, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);
    linklossAlertLevel.setValue(HIGH_ALERT, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);
    BluetoothGattService linklossService = new BluetoothGattService(LINKLOSS_SERVICE_UUID, BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);
    linklossService.addCharacteristic(linklossAlertLevel);
    mBluetoothGattServer.addService(linklossService);
}

private BluetoothGattServerCallback mGattServerCallbacks = new BluetoothGattServerCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicReadRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, int offset, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        DebugLogger.d(TAG, "[Proximity Server] onCharacteristicReadRequest " + device.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWriteRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean preparedWrite, boolean responseNeeded, int offset,
            byte[] value) {
        DebugLogger.d(TAG, "[Proximity Server] onCharacteristicWriteRequest " + device.getName());
        final int receivedValue = value[0];
        if (receivedValue != NO_ALERT) {
            Logger.i(mLogSession, "[Proximity Server] Immediate alarm request received: ON");
            playAlarm();
        } else {
            Logger.i(mLogSession, "[Proximity Server] Immediate alarm request received: OFF");
            stopAlarm();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothDevice device, int status, int newState) {
        DebugLogger.d(TAG, "[Proximity Server] onConnectionStateChange " + device.getName() + " status: " + status + " new state: " + newState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDescriptorReadRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, int offset, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor) {
        DebugLogger.d(TAG, "[Proximity Server] onDescriptorReadRequest " + device.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDescriptorWriteRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, boolean preparedWrite, boolean responseNeeded, int offset, byte[] value) {
        DebugLogger.d(TAG, "[Proximity Server] onDescriptorWriteRequest " + device.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onExecuteWrite(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, boolean execute) {
        DebugLogger.d(TAG, "[Proximity Server] onExecuteWrite " + device.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceAdded(final int status, final BluetoothGattService service) {
        DebugLogger.d(TAG, "[Proximity Server] onServiceAdded " + service.getUuid());

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // adding another service from callback thread fails on Samsung S4 with Android 4.3
                if (IMMEIDIATE_ALERT_SERVICE_UUID.equals(service.getUuid()))
                    addLinklossService();
                else {
                    DebugLogger.d(TAG, "[Proximity Server] Gatt server started");
                    Logger.i(mLogSession, "[Proximity Server] Gatt server started");
                    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
                        mBluetoothGatt = mDeviceToConnect.connectGatt(mContext, false, mGattCallback);
                        mDeviceToConnect = null;
                    } else {
                        mBluetoothGatt.connect();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
};

/**
 * Callbacks for activity {HTSActivity} that implements HTSManagerCallbacks interface activity use this method to register itself for receiving callbacks
 */
@Override
public void setGattCallbacks(ProximityManagerCallbacks callbacks) {
    mCallbacks = callbacks;
}

/**
 * Sets the log session that can be used to log events
 * 
 * @param logSession
 */
public void setLogger(LogSession logSession) {
    mLogSession = logSession;
}

@Override
public void connect(Context context, BluetoothDevice device) {
    mContext = context;
    // save the device that we want to connect to
    mDeviceToConnect = device;

    final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    if (preferences.getBoolean(ProximityActivity.PREFS_GATT_SERVER_ENABLED, true)) {
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        try {
            DebugLogger.d(TAG, "[Proximity Server] Starting Gatt server...");
            Logger.v(mLogSession, "[Proximity Server] Starting Gatt server...");
            openGattServer(context, bluetoothManager);
            addImmediateAlertService();
            // the BluetoothGattServerCallback#onServiceAdded callback will proceed further operations
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            // On Nexus 4&7 with Android 4.4 (build KRT16S) sometimes creating Gatt Server fails. There is a Null Pointer Exception thrown from addCharacteristic method.
            Logger.e(mLogSession, "[Proximity Server] Gatt server failed to start");
            Log.e(TAG, "Creating Gatt Server failed", e);
        }
    } else {
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            mBluetoothGatt = mDeviceToConnect.connectGatt(context, false, mGattCallback);
            mDeviceToConnect = null;
        } else {
            mBluetoothGatt.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void disconnect() {
    if (mBluetoothGatt != null) {
        userDisconnectedFlag = true;
        mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
        stopAlarm();
        closeGattServer();
    }
}

private void initializeAlarm(Context context) {
    final Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    mRingtoneAlarm = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
    mRingtoneAlarm.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);

    final Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    mRingtoneNotification = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
}

private void playNotification() {
    DebugLogger.d(TAG, "playNotification");
    mRingtoneNotification.play();
}

private void playAlarm() {
    DebugLogger.d(TAG, "playAlarm");
    final AudioManager am = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM), AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
    mRingtoneAlarm.play();
}

private void stopAlarm() {
    DebugLogger.d(TAG, "stopAlarm");
    mRingtoneAlarm.stop();
}

/**
 * BluetoothGatt callbacks for connection/disconnection, service discovery, receiving indication, etc
 */
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                DebugLogger.d(TAG, "Device connected");
                mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
                //This will send callback to ProximityActivity when device get connected
                mCallbacks.onDeviceConnected();
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                DebugLogger.d(TAG, "Device disconnected");
                if (userDisconnectedFlag) {
                    mCallbacks.onDeviceDisconnected();
                    userDisconnectedFlag = false;
                } else {
                    playNotification();
                    mCallbacks.onLinklossOccur();
                }
            }
        } else {
            mCallbacks.onError(ERROR_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE, status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            final List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
            for (BluetoothGattService service : services) {
                if (service.getUuid().equals(IMMEIDIATE_ALERT_SERVICE_UUID)) {
                    DebugLogger.d(TAG, "Immediate Alert service is found");
                    mAlertLevelCharacteristic = service.getCharacteristic(ALERT_LEVEL_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID);
                } else if (service.getUuid().equals(LINKLOSS_SERVICE_UUID)) {
                    DebugLogger.d(TAG, "Linkloss service is found");
                    mLinklossCharacteristic = service.getCharacteristic(ALERT_LEVEL_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID);
                } else if (service.getUuid().equals(BATTERY_SERVICE_UUID)) {
                    DebugLogger.d(TAG, "Battery service is found");
                    mBatteryCharacteristic = service.getCharacteristic(BATTERY_LEVEL_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID);
                }
            }
            if (mLinklossCharacteristic == null) {
                mCallbacks.onDeviceNotSupported();
                gatt.disconnect();
            } else {
                mCallbacks.onServicesDiscovered(mAlertLevelCharacteristic != null);
                writeLinklossAlertLevel(HIGH_ALERT);
            }
        } else {
            mCallbacks.onError(ERROR_DISCOVERY_SERVICE, status);
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi();
        DebugLogger.d(TAG, "Finished READING THE RSSI");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
        if (rssi != 0) {
        rssilevel = rssi; }
        else {
        rssilevel = 0; }
        DebugLogger.d(TAG, "READING THE RSSI");
    }




    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            if (characteristic.getUuid().equals(BATTERY_LEVEL_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)) {
                int batteryValue = characteristic.getValue()[0];
                mCallbacks.onBatteryValueReceived(batteryValue);
            }
        } else if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_INSUFFICIENT_AUTHENTICATION) {
            if (gatt.getDevice().getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                DebugLogger.w(TAG, ERROR_AUTH_ERROR_WHILE_BONDED);
                mCallbacks.onError(ERROR_AUTH_ERROR_WHILE_BONDED, status);
            }
        } else {
            mCallbacks.onError(ERROR_READ_CHARACTERISTIC, status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            if (characteristic.getUuid().equals(ALERT_LEVEL_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID)) {
                if (mBatteryCharacteristic != null) {
                    readBatteryLevel();
                }
            }
        } else if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_INSUFFICIENT_AUTHENTICATION) {
            if (gatt.getDevice().getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                DebugLogger.w(TAG, ERROR_AUTH_ERROR_WHILE_BONDED);
                mCallbacks.onError(ERROR_AUTH_ERROR_WHILE_BONDED, status);
            }
        } else {
            mCallbacks.onError(ERROR_WRITE_CHARACTERISTIC, status);
        }
    }
};

private BroadcastReceiver mBondingBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        final BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        final int bondState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, -1);
        final int previousBondState = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE, -1);

        // skip other devices
        if (!device.getAddress().equals(mBluetoothGatt.getDevice().getAddress()))
            return;

        DebugLogger.i(TAG, "Bond state changed for: " + device.getName() + " new state: " + bondState + " previous: " + previousBondState);

        if (bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING) {
            mCallbacks.onBondingRequired();
            return;
        }
        if (bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
            if (mLinklossCharacteristic != null) {
                writeLinklossAlertLevel(HIGH_ALERT);
            }
            mCallbacks.onBonded();
        }
    }
};

private void readBatteryLevel() {
    if (mBatteryCharacteristic != null) {
        DebugLogger.d(TAG, "reading battery characteristic");
        mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(mBatteryCharacteristic);
    } else {
        DebugLogger.w(TAG, "Battery Level Characteristic is null");
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private void readLinklossAlertLevel() {
    if (mLinklossCharacteristic != null) {
        DebugLogger.d(TAG, "reading linkloss alert level characteristic");
        mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(mLinklossCharacteristic);
    } else {
        DebugLogger.w(TAG, "Linkloss Alert Level Characteristic is null");
    }
}

private void writeLinklossAlertLevel(int alertLevel) {
    if (mLinklossCharacteristic != null) {
        DebugLogger.d(TAG, "writing linkloss alert level characteristic");
        mLinklossCharacteristic.setValue(alertLevel, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mLinklossCharacteristic);
    } else {
        DebugLogger.w(TAG, "Linkloss Alert Level Characteristic is not found");
    }
}

public void writeImmediateAlertOn() {
    if (mAlertLevelCharacteristic != null) {
        DebugLogger.d(TAG, "writing Immediate alert characteristic On");
        mAlertLevelCharacteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
        mAlertLevelCharacteristic.setValue(HIGH_ALERT, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mAlertLevelCharacteristic);
    } else {
        DebugLogger.w(TAG, "Immediate Alert Level Characteristic is not found");
    }
}

public void writeImmediateAlertOff() {
    if (mAlertLevelCharacteristic != null) {
        DebugLogger.d(TAG, "writing Immediate alert characteristic Off");
        mAlertLevelCharacteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE);
        mAlertLevelCharacteristic.setValue(NO_ALERT, BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8, 0);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mAlertLevelCharacteristic);
    } else {
        DebugLogger.w(TAG, "Immediate Alert Level Characteristic is not found");
    }
}

@Override
public void closeBluetoothGatt() {
    try {
        mContext.unregisterReceiver(mBondingBroadcastReceiver);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // the receiver must have been not registered or unregistered before
    }
    if (mBluetoothGatt != null) {
        mBluetoothGatt.close();
        mBluetoothGatt = null;
    }
    if (mBluetoothGattServer != null) {
        mBluetoothGattServer.close();
        mBluetoothGattServer = null;
    }
    mCallbacks = null;
    mLogSession = null;
    mRingtoneAlarm = mRingtoneNotification = null;
}
```

}

Comment: No idea what your problem is. And what do you want to do with this `ProximityManager temp = new ProximityManager(); int temp = temp.rssilevel;`. This won't even compile...

Comment: from the code i pasted, i want to take the public int rssilevel, and call it from another class in another .java file which is located in the same package. How would I do that, since ProximityManager, has context inside the (). example ProximityManager(context context)

Comment: you can just call `getrssi()`. Just make sure you import `ProximityManager`, and then you can call this method.

Comment: does not work, code says its not avaible

Comment: then you are importing it the wrong way. show the code where you try to import

Comment: Import javafilename; on top of next class. You cant just call getrssi()  you need a class container. Example how about you tell me gow to refrence it?

Comment: you import the class name, which should be the files name, right. and if you have done that, you CAN call getrssi(). what kind of a class container do you want??? there is no reason for a class container, you just want to call a function from your class. just show the code how you imported...